# What to do when bindingredirect does not work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, app-config

I am in a situation reminiscent of "DLL hell".  I am using a bunch of nuget packages which might muddle the circumstances, I suppose.

The complaint is at runtime that it cannot find System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

However, I have the following in my app.config:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I would expect that any attempt to load 4.0.0.0 would load 4.1.0.0 instead but that is not happening.  I do not know why.

It also might be relevant that this is happening in an old *unit test*.  The app.config is in the unit test project.

---

P.S.  I have seen other questions in this general area but they do not answer my issue as I am using 100% C# code here.

Comment: The problem is that the bindingRedirect worked.  As the exception message says, it **wants** 4.0.0.0 but you gave it 4.1.0.0 instead.  The number of programmers that want to meet the system.net.http programmers in a dark alley to get this resolved once and for all has to be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain.  I lost nearly a week this past summer on that.  I'm assuming that this is a .NET Framework (i.e., non-Core) project.  Remove the System.Net.Http NuGet package and all of the binding redirects for that assembly.  That "should just fix" your issue (no guarantees)

If you search around, you should find a note from someone on the Microsoft product team apologizing for the mess and saying that there should never have been a NuGet package for that (I think it's in a GitHub issues discussion).

This is from memory - sorry, I don't work there anymore so I can't check my notes.

Comment: There is no inclusion of the System.Net.Http nuget package in this circumstance.  I am using nuget packages but not that one.   I suspect that one of the nuget packages being included is bringing in the dependence on 4.0.0.0 but most of these packages are external and so out of my control. Sigh.